# Create type property from an array of strings

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type for an object where its properties are generated by an array of object.

Let's say to have a function that takes as argument an array objects, where the properties id are based on a type.
This function returns you an object where its properties are those ids.

How can I have a type, typescript help, for the returned object?

It is easier to explain what I want with an example:

```js
type Names = "input" | "button" | "form";
type FuncParam = { id: Names };
type FuncReturnType = ??????;

/*
 * Transfroms an array of object -> id: Names
 * to an object with ids as properties and hello as values.
*/
const defineSomethings = (somethings: FuncParam[]) => {

  const obj = {} as FuncReturnType; // init return object
  somethings.map(({ id }) => obj[id] = "hello"); // fill {} properties with "ids" as key and "hello" as value 

  return obj;
};

const A = defineSomethings(
  {
    id: "input"
  },
  {
    id: "form"
  }
);

const B = defineSomethings(
  {
    id: "button"
  }
);

/*° - °*/

// Typescript should show me available properties.
A.input // ✅
A.form // ✅
A.button // ❌

B.input // ❌
B.form // ❌
B.button // ✅
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wX1OQN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi @wonderflame 
Thank you, it works :)

(like the other answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor `defineSomethings()` to accept a generic argument `T extends FunctionParam`. Notice that the value argument `somthings` you pass to the function must either be an array or you'll have to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to accept an unknown amount of arguments.

Next define `FuncReturnType` as a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that maps all types of the `id` property (`"input" | "button" | "form"`)

```
type FuncReturnType<T extends FuncParam[]> = {
  [K in T[number] as K["id"]]: "hello";
};

type Test = FuncReturnType<[{id: "input"}]>;
//   ^? type Test = {input: "hello";}
```

Finally, fix the `implicit any` compiler errors in the definition of `defineSomethings()` by adding an explicit type of `{[x: PropertyKey]: string}` (You can also type `x: string`, it doesn't really matter here, I'd claim) to `obj` and return `obj` `as FuncReturnType<T[]>` using [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

---

Now, let's put everything together:

```
type Names = "input" | "button" | "form";
type FuncParam = {id: Names};

type FuncReturnType<T extends FuncParam[]> = {
  [K in T[number] as K["id"]]: "hello";
};

const defineSomethings = <T extends FuncParam>(somethings: T[]) => {
  const obj: {[x: PropertyKey]: string} = {};
  somethings.map(({id}) => (obj[id] = "hello"));

  return obj as FuncReturnType<T[]>;
};

const a = defineSomethings([
  {
    id: "input"
  },
  {
    id: "form"
  }
]);

const b = defineSomethings([
  {
    id: "button"
  }
]);

a.input; // ✅
a.form; // ✅
a.button; // ❌

b.input; // ❌
b.form; // ❌
b.button; // ✅
```

Comment: nice! very well explained. To be honest I've tried many things and I came accros the documentation you shared but I was too behind. Need to work on my theory!

(you are right, in my example I forgot to `[` the parameter of defineSomethings `]`)

Answer (score -1):

```
type Names = "input" | "button" | "form";
type FuncParam = { id: Names };

type FuncReturnType<T extends FuncParam[]> = {
  [K in T[number]['id']]: string;
};

const defineSomethings = <T extends FuncParam[]>(somethings: T): FuncReturnType<T> => {
  const obj = {} as FuncReturnType<T>;

  somethings.forEach(({ id }) => {
    obj[id] = "hello";
  });

  return obj;
};

const A = defineSomethings([
  {
    id: "input"
  },
  {
    id: "form"
  }
]);

const B = defineSomethings([
  {
    id: "button"
  }
]);

A.input; // ✅
A.form;  // ✅
A.button; // ❌

B.input; // ❌
B.form;  // ❌
B.button; // ✅
```

Comment: Please don't just paste a chunk uf code. Explain what you did and why.

Comment: `obj[id] = "hello";` shows an error: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Names' can't be used to index type 'FuncReturnType<T>'.
  Property 'input' does not exist on type 'FuncReturnType<T>'.(7053)" https://tsplay.dev/m3VxyN